# UIAlertView on main queue crashing.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uialertview, exc-bad-access

I have an issue showing a `UIAlertView` on the main thread. I'm not sure why but it keeps crashing, despite me running on the main thread. The following block is on the background thread, but I have the alert on the main as below:

```
void (^removeFromCalendar)(NSString *, NSString *, EKEventStore *) = ^(NSString *error, NSString *eventKey, EKEventStore *eventDB) {
    EKEvent *myEvent = [eventDB eventWithIdentifier:eventKey];
    NSError *err = noErr;

    if(myEvent != NULL && myEvent != (id)[NSNull null]) {
        [eventDB removeEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
    } else {

        // Event was not found, nothing to do
        return;
    }

    [eventDB release];

    if (!err || err == noErr) {
        NSLog(@"Deleted event %@", myEvent.title);

        // Show alert on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Showing the alert for unattending
            NSString *resultString = @"This event was removed from your calendar.";
            UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message:resultString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] autorelease];
            [alert show];
        });

        return;
    }

    error = err.description;
};
```

If I comment out the bottom where it shows the alert, everything is fine. But for the alert, I keep getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. Can somebody explain why? It's on the correct thread, and I cant for the life of me understand where the memory issue could come from!

Comment: If you don't have a breakpoint set on Objective-C exceptions, add one.  It **usually** produces better error information than EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: How do I do that? Is that through the profiler?

Comment: The left view of Xcode's main screen has a set of icons at the top.  One of them's called the Breakpoint Navigator.  Open that view and there's a '+' at the bottom for adding a breakpoint.

Comment: did you try using `dispatch_sync` instead of `dispatch_async`? i've had some weird issues with this in the past

Comment: I can't imagine this will actually help but get rid of the extra `nil` after the `otherButtonTitles:` parameter when you create the `UIAlertView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you view is being released when you finish until you finish with the background queue. So, for safety why dont you use it like this;

```
...........
  UIViewController __weak *myController = self;
 dispathch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{ 
   UIViewController __strong *myStrongController = myController;
 ...............
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(myStrongController){
            // Showing the alert for unattending
            NSString *resultString = @"This event was removed from your calendar.";
            UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message:resultString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] autorelease];
            [alert show];
            }
        });
}).
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you present an alert view:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"<#(NSString *)#>" message:@"<#(NSString *)#>" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"<#(NSString *)#>" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using dispatch_async, why not use the objective C call:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread
```

You might have to package it up in its own method.  Alternatively, call it using:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myAlertMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25]
```

These methods have been tried and true since day 1.